# Is it compulsory to use to include toolbar to use coordinator layout effects?

Tags: android

I want to achieve the effect which is easily achieved by coordinator layout but I don't want to include the toolbar in it. I am trying to animate view below my toolbar(like shrinking image) when user scrolls.

Is it compulsory to include toolbar for using coordinator layout, any idea?

Comment: No, you don't have to include a toolbar. Did you try before asking?

Comment: Yes I tried that but somehow failed to achieve.. now got it running.